# My local Git "master" branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits, but nothing I have tried shows me the difference

Tags: git

I accidentally did some work on master, so I did some googling on how to commit those changes to a different branch other than master. I found this:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
$ git checkout -b BugFix
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git commit -m 'Fixed the merge conflicts.'
$ git status
```

Which "seemed" to have fixed my issue, but it appears it made things worse.

I have tried all of this:

```
$ git diff
$ git diff local remote
$ git diff master
$ git diff master origin/master
$ git diff master..origin/master
$ git diff origin
$ git diff origin/master
$ git diff origin/master master
$ git diff origin/master..master
```

None of these commands produces any output whatsoever, just back to my prompmt.

Originally:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Our master is protected, so when I do this:

```
$ git push
```

I get this message:

```
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 233 bytes | 233.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Analyzing objects... (1/1) (4 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (21 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (45 ms)
To https://url/to/master/branch
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://url/to/master/branch'
```

When I try:

```
$ git pull
```

I get this:

```
Already up to date.
```

At this point, all I want to do is see what has been changed so, maybe, I can blow away my local master and redo the changes manually.

How do I do this?

---

As Requested, the output of `git log` for the month of August:

```
commit a290975977b819d6719cd4e2e96f5d0ba9b3bc76 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 11d13f4 59cdeac
Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
Date:   Tue Aug 31 14:44:24 2021 -0400

    Fixed the merge conflicts.

commit 59cdeace599969328c073a226205c9f3da12ab79 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
Date:   Tue Aug 31 11:58:32 2021 -0400

    ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ comments ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

commit 11d13f421f3f6c7f8ff8e18cf0d95a005c0465bb
Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
Date:   Thu Aug 19 15:21:28 2021 -0400

    ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ comments ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

commit 5e86a703a78a8065c322d116bb6e94070fb63cef
Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
Date:   Wed Aug 18 09:48:46 2021 -0400

    ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ comments ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

commit 2a2974e8a84b4728880538e3140ba6ead4f69c3b
Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
Date:   Mon Aug 9 10:26:11 2021 -0400

    ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ comments ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

commit b5756c095ab7321f679666e749a884af6b3f5213
Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
Date:   Tue Aug 3 12:07:01 2021 -0400

    ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ comments ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: What does `git log --graph --online --decorate --all` show?

Comment: @chepner I get the error `fatal: unrecognized argument: --online`. However, if I remove that switch I get what looks like a historical tree of information. None of it, however, is the `diff` I am looking for.

Comment: Typo: `--oneline`. The idea is to see just what the relation between your two branches is, to see what diff command you need.

Comment: It could be that there is no diff but just 2 commits whose changes have no effect in the end. Can you share the output of the `git log`?

Comment: @GaëlJ I have posted the output of `git log` for the month of August.

Comment: I meant the output of chepner command

Comment: @GaëlJ What is "chepner"? I did a `$ git --help` and saw no "chepner" option.

Comment: @Brian the command of user chepner, 1st comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your `git log` output, the two commits that are on `master` but not on `origin/master` are `a290975977b819d6719cd4e2e96f5d0ba9b3bc76` and `11d13f421f3f6c7f8ff8e18cf0d95a005c0465bb`.

Commit `a290975977b819d6719cd4e2e96f5d0ba9b3bc76` is the commit that you have, currently, as the *tip commit* of your `master` branch.  The tip commit is the commit that is the last commit on that branch at the moment.  To understand this, see the notes below.

Commit `a290975977b819d6719cd4e2e96f5d0ba9b3bc76` is a *merge commit*, with two parents.  We see this here:

> ```
> commit a290975977b819d6719cd4e2e96f5d0ba9b3bc76 (HEAD -> master)
> Merge: 11d13f4 59cdeac
> Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
> Date:   Tue Aug 31 14:44:24 2021 -0400
>
>    Fixed the merge conflicts.
> ```

Note the `Merge: 11d13f4 59cdeac` line, which is how we know that this is a merge commit.  The two hash IDs after `Merge:` are abbreviated.  One of them is `11d13f421f3f6c7f8ff8e18cf0d95a005c0465bb`, abbreviated to just `11d13f4`.  The other one is short for the next commit that we see in the `git log` output:

> ```
> commit 59cdeace599969328c073a226205c9f3da12ab79 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
> Author: MyUsername <myusername@myhost>
> Date:   Tue Aug 31 11:58:32 2021 -0400
>
>    ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ comments ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
> ```

Note the parenthesized `origin/master, origin/HEAD` here as well.  As with the parenthesized `HEAD -> master` above, these are *decorations* that `git log` adds to tell us that this particular commit can be found under the listed names.  In this case commit `59cdeac` can be found using the name `origin/master`, or using the name `origin/HEAD`.  Commit `a290975` can be found using the name `HEAD`.

#### What to do about all this

If your commit `11d13f4` is actually *valuable*, stick a branch name on it:

```
git branch save 11d13f4
```

(feel free to call the branch something more meaningful than `save`).  Then, while on `master`, run:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

You're all fixed up and your commit that you made on `master` is now on `save` instead.

#### What's going on, or, how to understand the above

Git is all about *commits*.  Git stores files, but those files are stored inside *commits*.  Git has branches, but those branches are made up of *commits*.  You can push and fetch (the nearest opposite of `push` is `fetch`, not `pull`, due to an early mistake of sorts) to send work from your Git repository to another Git repository, or get work from another Git repository into your Git repository; this transfers *commits*.  So commits are really the thing.

This means you need to know what a commit is and does for you.  You already know that commits are *numbered*, with these horrible ugly random-looking things like `a290975977b819d6719cd4e2e96f5d0ba9b3bc76`.  These are *hash IDs*, which are numbers (very big numbers) that are expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  They're not nice neat sequential counts: you can't go to commit #1, then #2, and so on, in a nice simple order.  The hash IDs themselves are actually the result of running a cryptographic checksum function over the *full contents* of each commit; Git guarantees that each full hash ID will be unique.

(Shortening a hash ID, as we usually do because they're so ugly, raises the chance of running into a non-unique abbreviation, but `a290975` is still sufficient in your own repository.  Probably even `a290` is good enough at the moment.  You'll find that Git uses longer abbreviations once your repository gets huge.)

Because these are so ugly and un-human-usable, we don't actually *use* the numbers most of the time.  We might, now and then, use the mouse to cut-and-paste one (that's what I did with your `git log` output).  But these are the "true names" of the commits.

What's *inside* a commit is just as important.  Each commit stores two things:

- Every commit stores a full snapshot of all of your source files.  The files are stored here in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  Only Git can read these, and literally nothing can write them.

  The de-duplication means that when you make *new* commits, they don't really take lots of space, even though each commit still has every file.  They just all *share* the files whose contents match.  If you changed just one file out of 3000 files and then made a new commit, the new commit re-used the 2999 unchanged files: it only had to cause one new file to be stored.
- Besides the snapshot, each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  It includes a date-and-time stamp (technically, two date-and-time stamps).  And, each commit stores the raw hash ID of some *earlier* commits.

Most commits store exactly *one* previous commit hash ID.  This makes these commits *ordinary* commits.  The stored hash ID is the *parent* of the commit, and we say that this ordinary commit *points to* its parent.

Suppose we have a new and very small repository, with just three commits in it.  These commits have random-looking hash IDs, but let's call them `A`, `B`, and `C`, and say that they were made in that order.  If we *draw* these three commits, we would draw them like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C`, the third (and current) commit, has an arrow coming out of it, pointing to commit `B`.  (In reality, commit `C` stores the big ugly hash ID of earlier commit `B`.)  Commit `B` in turn has an arrow coming out of it, pointing to `A` (really, commit `B` stores `A`'s hash ID in `B`'s metadata).  But what about commit `A`?

Well, `A` is the *very first* commit.  There's no earlier commit for it to point backwards *to*.  So it just doesn't.  That lets a program like `git log` *stop*.

If commit `C` is the *current* commit, and we run `git log`, Git will print out information about commit `C`.  Then `git log` will follow the arrow back to earlier commit `B`, and print out information about `B`; then `git log` will follow the arrow back to `A` and print out `A`; and then there's nothing left, so `git log` can quit: we've seen all the history that there is.

The important parts to remember here are: **The commits are the history.  Each commit points backwards.  Git starts at the end and works backwards.**  The end, in this case, is commit `C`.

Here's one problem we haven't talked about, though.  Remember that the real hash IDs are random-looking.  How are we supposed to know which commit is the *latest?*  There are a lot of possible answers—it's a good exercise to think about all the ways you might solve this problem—but the answer Git uses is: *branch names*.

#### Branch names find the last commit

Let's get a little lazy and draw our three commits like this, with just one arrow coming from a *branch name* to point to the *last* commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Let's now create a new, second branch name, `develop`, and make *both names* point to commit `C`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master
```

No matter which *branch name* we use, we'll be telling Git to use *commit `C`*.  But in a moment, it's going to matter which branch name we're using.  So let's use the special name `HEAD` to mark one name, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

This means we are, as `git status` would say, `on branch master`.  The special name `HEAD` is "attach to" the branch name `master`, and not to any other branch name.

If we now run `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`, here's what happens:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

We're still using commit `C`, but we're using it *through* the name `develop` now.

Now let's make one new commit.  You already know how to do that—change some file(s), maybe add new file(s), run `git add` on them, and run `git commit`.  The `git commit` command will make a new snapshot of *every* file, de-duplicating them all against every other file ever committed in this repository (so they won't take extra space if they don't have to).  We'll ignore the mechanism behind this, although it is pretty interesting, and just observe the outcome:

- Git gathers any needed metadata, such as your name and email address, and a log message, from you or your `.gitconfig` or whatever;
- Git uses the *current commit's* hash ID (the real hash ID of `C`) to set up the *parent* in the new metadata;
- Git makes a snapshot of all files;
- Git writes all this out to make a new commit, which gets some new big ugly hash ID, but we'll just call it `D`; and
- Git does something tricky.  We'll see *what* in just a moment.

Let's draw new commit D, on a separate line, leaving out the branch names:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

Now let's put the branch names back in.  The branch `master` should still point to commit `C`, so it does.  But new commit `D` is now the *latest* commit on `develop`, so branch name `develop` should point to `D`, not `C`.  And it does!

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

What Git does in that sneaky-trick final step of `git commit` is: *Write the new commit's hash ID into the **branch name** to which the special name `HEAD` is attached.*

If we now `git checkout master`, we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

We're back to the old commit `C`, on `master`.  New commit `D` is still there, with its snapshot and metadata.  It's at the tip of branch `develop`.  The commit that `D` points backwards to is existing commit `C`.

A moment ago, both branch names selected commit `C`, and commits `A-B-C` were on *both branches*.  Now `develop` selects commit `D`.  Importantly, commits `A-B-C` are **still on both branches**.  In fact, commit `A` will generally be on *every* branch we make.  If we make one new commit `E` on `master` now, though, we get this:

```
        E   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

This is what branch *names* in Git are all about.  They simply find the *last* commit in some sequence of commits.  From there, Git will work backwards, one commit at a time, as needed to visit all the commits.

When there's some kind of fork, as there is here at commit `C`, you have "two branches".  If the forks don't rejoin later, you need two *names* to find these commits, because real hash IDs are random-looking and impossible to tell apart.  The two names will find the *latest* commit on each branch.

#### Merging

Let's consider the following pair of branches:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Commits up through `H` are on both branches.  Commits `I-J` are only on `branch1`, and commits `K-L` are—at least *currently*—only on `branch2`.

We now run `git checkout branch1` or `git switch branch1` to attach `HEAD` there:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

Then we run `git merge branch2`.  This performs a true merge (there are some "fake merges" in Git, which we won't cover here for space reasons), and it involves finding the *merge base*, which is the best *shared* commit, on both branches.  That's pretty obviously commit `H` here.  Git combines work done on the two branches.  If Git is able to do all the combining on its own, Git makes a new commit.

Normally, our next commit `M` would just have *one* parent:

```
          I--J--M?
         /
...--G--H
        ...
```

but that's not the case for `git merge` and true merges.  Instead, Git makes `M` as a *merge commit*, with *two* parents.  New commit `M` points back to commit `J` as usual, but *also points back to commit `L`*, like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

The *name* `branch1` now selects merge commit `M`, rather than ordinary commit `J`.  Remember, the ordinary commits are the ones that go back just to one previous commit.  Merge commits are the ones like `M` that go back to two commits.<sup>1</sup>  Meanwhile, Git writes `M`'s hash ID into the branch name, as usual, so now `branch1` selects commit `M`.

**When Git works backwards through a merge commit, it visits both parent chains.**  So the history from `branch1` now includes all the commits shown here!  Commits `K-L`, which used to be only on `branch2`, are now on *both branches*.

If we are done doing all our work on `branch2`, it is now safe to delete that branch name entirely.  We—or Git—will still find the commits by going backwards through merge commit `M`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, a Git merge commit can have two *or more* parents.  The "or more" part is mainly just for showing off.   We won't cover them here.

---

#### Remote-tracking names

Git finds commits by starting from names, such as branch names.  But *branch* names are not the only kind of names Git has:

- *Branch* names locate one specific commit.

  You give a branch name to `git checkout` and that one specific commit *becomes* the *current commit*.  As you make new commits, they point back to the older commits, and Git *automatically drags the branch name forward*.
- *Tag* names locate one specific commit, just like branch names.

  Git can and will work backwards from a tag name, but that's not really how *humans* usually use them.  Unlike a branch name, if you give a tag name to `git checkout`, you won't get *on* it.  Instead, Git will go into what it calls *detached HEAD* mode.  This isn't a mode for doing new work, in general, so you'd want to create and switch to a branch name here.

  Tag names have another special feature that branch names don't: tag names are allowed to point to things that aren't *commits*.  We can use this to create what Git calls *annotated tags*.  We won't show them here, though.
- *Remote-tracking* names locate one specific commit.

  This seems a lot like branch names.  In fact, Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names* (which I think is kind of wrong).  Like tag names, you can't get "on" them: giving one to `git checkout` gets you that same *detached HEAD* mode thing.

  The point of these remote-tracking names, though, is really to help your Git—your various Git commands operating on your repository—remember stuff about some *other* Git repository.  This is where `git fetch` and, to a lesser extent, `git push` come in.

In fact, Git has even more kinds of names, but the kind we really care about here is the remote-tracking name.  The name `origin/master`, for instance, is a remote-tracking name.

Understanding these names is actually pretty easy.  When you run `git clone` to *copy* someone else's (or even your own) repository to a new repository, Git will save away the URL you use.  For instance, if you run:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/git/git
```

you will get a clone of the Git repository for Git (the one on GitHub is technically just a mirror, but is a fine place to get a clone from as it's updated frequently).  When you do this, your Git records the URL, `ssh://git@github.com/git/git`, under a name called a *remote*.  This name enables your Git to refer back to `ssh://git@github.com/git/git` again without having to type the full URL:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

for instance, or:

```
git fetch origin
```

reaches back to that same URL.

There is a Git responder *at* that URL, connected to the clone of the Git repository for Git that resides at that URL.  So when your Git connects to this other Git, it can see that repository.

That other repository *is a repository*.  ("Well duh", you might say.)  But that means that the repository over there *has branch names*.  So your Git can *copy* these to *your* repository.

Here's the tricky part: if they were to just slam the other Git's branch names into your repository as your *branch* names, that would *overwrite the hash IDs stored in **your** branch names*.  So your Git won't take any of their *branch* names **as** *branch* names.

In fact, during your initial clone operation, your Git will copy *all of their commits*,<sup>2</sup> but *none* of their *branches!*  Your Git takes each of their *branch names*, such as `master` or `develop`, and *changes them*.  Your Git sticks `origin/` in front of each name.<sup>3</sup>  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`.

Once you have all their commits, with all their branch names renamed to remote-tracking names, *then* your Git creates *one* (local) branch name.  The branch your Git creates is the one you select with your `-b` option at `git clone` time.  If you don't select one, your Git asks their Git what branch name they recommend.  GitHub will typically recommend `main` or `master`,<sup>4</sup> so that's the name you will get if you don't ask for one in particular.

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, your Git copies only all the *reachable* commits from the branches and tags and other names that your Git copies (with any modifications needed).  But usually that's "all commits".

<sup>3</sup>Technically, these remote-tracking names are in a completely separate namespace.  That protects you in case you do something silly like create a (local) branch named `origin/hello`.  The local branches live in the `refs/heads/` namespace, and the remote-tracking names live in `refs/remotes/`, with the remote name and another slash added.  Git just normally snips off `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` when that's unambiguous.

<sup>4</sup>GitHub provide a web interface where you can select the "default branch" for cloning.  This used to be `master`, last year or so; now it's `main`.

---

#### Conclusion

If you made it this far, congratulations!

In your repository, when you run `git fetch`, your Git will:

- call up the other Git (at `origin`, or you can add more remotes or rename this one);
- collect any new commits they have that you should get;
- create or update any remote-tracking names that find the new commits.

If you add `--prune` or `-p` to your `git fetch`, your Git will *delete* any *stale* remote-tracking names.  A stale name is one that is for a branch they had before, but have deleted.  That is, suppose they had branch `work` and you ran `git fetch`.  Your Git created `origin/work`.  Then they, whoever they are, were done with `work` and deleted it.  Your `git fetch` will leave your `origin/work` around *unless* you tell your Git to prune it.

If you run `git pull`, your Git runs `git fetch`, then runs a second Git command: usually `git merge`.  You can select `git rebase` as the second command to run.  The only reason to do this is that, having fetched commits *from* them, you usually want to *incorporate* these commits into *your current branch*.  That's what the second command does.

If you have your `git pull` run `git merge`, or run it yourself, you may get a *merge commit*.  The merge command is complicated, so there's no guarantee that you *will* get a merge commit; we have not covered it in detail.

If you do get a merge commit and did not want it, you will need to run `git reset` to get rid of it.  Reset—which we haven't covered here either—is a very large and complicated Git command, with a lot of sharp edges; be careful when using it.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: Amazing answer, how did you get such a clear understanding.

Comment: @KnownUnknown: Been using Git since the late 2000s (around 2006 or 2007), crashed into many of its bugs, am on the Git internals mailing list now, have contributed some patches, etc.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation of git on the web.